# SF298 package giving undefined control sequence error

Tags: errors, packages

I am trying to use the SF298 package for latex and it gives an undefined control sequence error. The error is as follows:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\ExecuteOptions ...eserved@a \CurrentOption \@nil
l.104 \ExecuteOptions{config,nofloatlongboxes}
```

The test latex file I am using is as follows:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{sf298}

\title{Test Title}
\author{author}

\ReportDate{10--06--1996}
\ReportType{Final}
\DatesCovered{1 June 1996 --- 31 May 1999}
\Title{Final Report Title}
\ContractNumber{DACA99--99--C--9999}
\Author{Uthor, Joe, A., and Ditor, Jane, E.}
\PerformingOrg{Test}
\SponsoringAgency{Test2}
\Abstract{Abstract}
\SubjectTerms{keywords; associated words; other words}
\AbstractLimitation{UU}
\ResponsiblePerson{Mr.\ Joe A. Uthor}
\RPTelephone{(412) 555--9999}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle

  \MakeRptDocPage

  \section{Introduction}     % section 1.1
  \subsection{History}       % subsection 1.1.1

  \section{Introduction}     % section 2.1
  \subsection{Usage}         % subsection 2.1.1

\end{document}
```

[David Carlisle]

the example can be reduced to

```
\begin{filecontents}{zz.sty}

  \usepackage{totpages}

\DeclareOption{config}{\def\sf@config{Y}}


\ExecuteOptions{config}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{zz}

\stop
```

On the face of it, seems to be a bug in `totpages` or one of the packages it loads.

Comment: Related:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108374/how-can-i-construct-a-page-layout-with-framed-boxes/108391#108391

Comment: I updated the example with \title and \author, but I still get the error. I also tried deleting all other files in the folder as well.

Comment: Sorry I deleted previous comments: with your updated example I get the error you get.

Comment: If you remove the `[titlepage]` option (as in your original) then you get no error, I've no idea what the `sf298` package is supposed to do, or if it is supposed to support titlepage, so I'm not sure if just removing the option is a possibility for you

Comment: I'm out of time today, but I add a simpler example to your question

Comment: @David The sf298 package is used to create a Standard Form 298 Report Documentation Page for government reports. This page allows the report to be catalougued in one of the US government document repositories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reasons, `\CurrentOption` is defined to expand `\@nil` and not to empty, as  LaTeX expects.

This seems to ba a bug in `totpages`, which processes options in a personalized way.

The problem may be solved by loading `totpages` before any package that loads it and to add `\def\CurrentOption{}` after it.

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{totpages}
\def\CurrentOption{} % fix bug in totpages

\usepackage{sf298}
```

In this way, `sf298` will not load `totpages` again and the problem will not show.

Comment: So, I guess my question now is, can I fix the totpages package and push it up to CTAN?

Comment: @LWhitson2 there is an email and postal address for bug reports in the comment at the top of `totpages.sty`