# How can I get the center of a scaled image wherever I want it---(x,y)---in the document?

Tags: graphics, formatting

According to some coordinate system, whatever that may be, how can I position a scaled image where I want it in the document using the center of the image as the point of reference? For example, something like this:

```
\being{whatever}(4cm,6cm)
     \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{img.jpg}
\end{whatever}
```

---

Here is my minimal working whatever:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{something}
\title{Cartesian closed categories and the price of eggs}
\author{Jane Doe}
\date{September 1994}
\begin{document}
   \maketitle
   Hello world!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Should this be on every page, or an individual page? See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page helps.

Comment: First page only.

Comment: How can you modify this for images?

Comment: Modify what, exactly?

Comment: How can I modify the \AbsolutePosition command so that it positions images instead of circle objects.

Comment: Change the `\draw` command to `\draw [#1]  ($(current page.south west) + (\BottomLeftX,\BottomLeftY) + (#2,#3)$) node{#4};` and use `\includegraphics` in the last argument.

Comment: Or `\draw [#1]  ($(current page.south west) + (#2,#3)$) node{#4};` if you want the position relative to the bottom left corner of the page, and not the bottom left of the text area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace the text that was being placed with the appropriate `\includegraphics`:

[image]

Below is an adaption of [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169836/4301) to use `\includegraphics[<<options>>]{<<file>>}` instead of given text.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


%% ------ https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169836/4301
%% Following obtained from \layout. May need adjustment based on class and
%% page settings.  Alternatively, can set these to 0pt and then position will
%% be relative to bottom left of page.
\newcommand*{\BottomLeftX}{1.0in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin}%
\newcommand*{\BottomLeftY}{\paperheight-1.0in-\voffset-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\textheight}%

\newcommand*{\AbsolutePosition}[4][]{%
    % #1 = tikz options
    % #2 = x (from south west corner of page
    % #3 = y
    % #4 = text
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, ultra thick]
        %\draw [shift={(#2,#3)},#1]  (current page.south west) circle (2pt) 
        \draw [#1]  ($(current page.south west) + (\BottomLeftX,\BottomLeftY) + (#2,#3)$) 
            %circle (2pt) %  adding `[opacity=0.2]` to the node below will let you see this reference point
                node[] {#4};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\title{Cartesian closed categories and the price of eggs}
\author{Jane Doe}
\date{September 1994}
\begin{document}
   \maketitle
   Hello world!

\AbsolutePosition[fill=red,draw=red]{7.0cm}{12.0cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{../images/EiffelWide}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about multiple images? I can place my signature in the right place, but when I try to position a pspicture barcode under the address I have in my document things start flying around...

Comment: @Blarxly: You should be able to place as many objects as you want. But if that does not work, you should post a new question with a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that reproduces the problem.