# I need help width \rule

Tags: rules

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\color{blue}
\rule{\paperwidth}{7.5cm}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

I just want to make a box which is blue, has paperwidth and is placed at the bottom and is 7.5cm high. How to do that?

Thank you very much in advance :)

PS! It would be nice if I also could write a text which begins 7 cm from the right edge and goes to maximum 2 cm of the right edge and starts two centimeters under the blue beginning and ends to cm before bottom (white text) :D

And a picture which is 2 cms from each edge of the paper (also in the blue box) and is 9 cm long.

[image: Example picture]

Comment: By "placed at the bottom" are you referring to the bottom of the page? Or the bottom of the text block? Perhaps you can provide us with a graphic of the output... even if you were to draw it on a piece of paper with a pen and include it in your post.

Comment: I am refering to the bottom of the page :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

load these packs in the preamble

```
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{calc}
```

then:

```
\colorbox{blue}{
\parbox[b][7.5cm][t]{\textwidth}{\hspace*{7cm}
\parbox[t][5.5cm][t]{\textwidth-9cm}{\textcolor{red}{\\[2cm]
 Some text that non makes sense\hfill at all,\vfill just for practicing\ldots\hfill the example }}
%\makebox[0.5\textwidth-9cm][l]{ \textcolor{white}{Some text that non makes sense at all, just for practicing the example }} 
 }
}
```

this will produce this output :
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Based on my answer at [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page/169831#169831)

REVISED to make solution with nested `\stackinsets`.  Note:  The text will be vertically centered in the white box.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{stackengine}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddThispageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}
\begin{document}
\def\blocktext{%
  This is a test of text in my parbox. Will it wrap properly?  I think it will.}
\atxy{0in}{11in}{%
  \stackinset{r}{2.5cm}{c}{0cm}{\parbox[c]{4cm}{\blocktext}}{%
  \stackinset{l}{2cm}{b}{2cm}{\includegraphics[width=9cm,height=3.5cm]{example-image-a}}{%
  \stackinset{r}{2cm}{b}{2cm}{\textcolor{white}{\rule{5cm}{3.5cm}}}{%
    \textcolor{blue}{\rule{\paperwidth}{7.5cm}}%
  }}}%
}
\lipsum[1-4]\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

ORIGINAL SOLUTION (without stacks):

I draw the blue with a big `\rule`, and then overlay a white block for the future text, and an image, and finally a `\parbox` for the text.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddThispageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}
\begin{document}
\atxy{0in}{11in}{\textcolor{blue}{\rule{\paperwidth}{7.5cm}}}
\atxy{\dimexpr\paperwidth-7cm}{\dimexpr11in-2cm}{\textcolor{white}{%
  \rule{5cm}{3.5cm}}}
\atxy{2cm}{\dimexpr11in-2cm}{%
  \includegraphics[width=9cm,height=3.5cm]{example-image-a}}
\atxy{\dimexpr\paperwidth-6.5cm}{\dimexpr11in-4.8cm}{\parbox[t]{4cm}{%
  This is a test of text in my parbox. Will it wrap properly?  I think it will.}}

\lipsum[1-4]\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \fill[blue] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,7)$);
    \fill[white] ($(current page.south west)+(2,2)$) rectangle ($(current page.south west)+(2,2)+(9,3)$);
    \fill[white] ($(current page.south east)+(-2,2)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(-2,2)+(-7,3)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you want to add some text, you can use `\node[text width = 9cm, text height = 2.5cm, align = left] at ($(current page.south west)+(6.5,4.5)$) {text goes here};` or something like that.