# latex - place picture at top left of coverpage

Tags: graphics, titles

I need to have the coverpage of my phd dissertion match a stupid word template from my university. While the whole layout is pretty set i'm unable to place to logo/picture in the top left of the coverpage (only) as I am required to (!). Right now its sitting in the middle of the coverpage. I'm using the title function in a report class-document. This is really the first document I've made i Latex so my Latex-skills aren't quite top level yet :)

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}       
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=23mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{Fancy header}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO, CE]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyfoot[CO, RE]{John McClane}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\title{
{Fancy title}\\
{\large PhD dissertation}\\
    \vspace{15mm}
\includegraphics[scale=1.5]{AUlogo}\\
    \vspace{15mm}
{\large Faculty of Health}\\
{\small Department of Boring PhDs}
}
\author
    {John McClane\\
    Master of Disaster}

\date{May 2014}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Consider reading up on [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169808/5764)

Comment: I realize that and thanks, but after hours of reading tips that didn't help i posted - and voila, thank you internet!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I agree with Werner's comment that the cited question provides various excellent means to do that, here I give an alternative answer, in which the picture is placed relative to the words "Fancy Title".  The `\raisebox` dimension (2in) and the `\hspace` dimension (2.2in) may be adjusted to suit.  The 2in is the vertical gap between the top of "Fancy Title" and the bottom of the picture, while 2.2in is the horizontal distance between the right edge of the image and the right edge of the words "Fancy title"

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}       
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=23mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{Fancy header}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO, CE]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyfoot[CO, RE]{John McClane}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\title{
{\def\stackalignment{r}\def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \stackon[0pt]{Fancy title}{\smash{%
  \raisebox{2in}{\includegraphics[scale=1.5]{AUlogo}}\hspace{2.2in}}}}\\
{\large PhD dissertation}\\
    \vspace{15mm}
{\large Faculty of Health}\\
{\small Department of Boring PhDs}
}
\author
    {John McClane\\
    Master of Disaster}

\date{May 2014}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]