# Avoid upsizing of images globally

Tags: graphics, resize

When I use common options of `\includegraphics` like `width`, `height`, `scale`, etc. I would like the resulting size of the image never exceeds its natural size.

In case of `width`, replacing it with the `max width` option ([borrowed from `adjustbox` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145294/28685)) it's a solution, but what about `scale`?

And what if I want to avoid upsizing of images **globally**?

P.S. I think that a nice solution would be adding a new option to `\includegraphics` like did some answers to this other question: [Size image by area](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/446660)

Comment: Why using `scale` at all?

Comment: scale is surely not an issue at all. you are just saying the scale factor is at most 1 so that's an author requirement not something for latex to check.

Comment: @egreg Actually I use `scale` very rarely, but I would like the solution to be able to avoid upsizing of any image over its natural size also if I use `scale` or any other way to resize an image (at least with `\includegraphics`).

Comment: A case may arise if you are writing a template that uploads images later,  
provided by a  user. You may want to keep images within certain dimensions, 
except if they are smaller than the allotted space.

In that case, you should check the actual dimensions of the image to be inserted and then decide which `\includegraphics` setup to apply.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185272/161015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick fix.  THE MWE should produce three identical images and one smaller image.  Note that `\includelimit` only supports size changes.

BTW, this also answers the linked question.  Also, do not use `\dimen0` with `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\includelimit}[2][]% will get bad results with [rotate]
{\bgroup
  \sbox0{\includegraphics{#2}}%
  \sbox1{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \dimen1=\ht0
  \ifdim\ht1<\dimen1 \dimen1=\ht1\fi
  \dimen2=\wd0
  \ifdim\wd1<\dimen2 \dimen2=\wd1\fi
  \includegraphics[width=\dimen2, height=\dimen1]{#2}%
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\includelimit[width=20cm]{example-image}
\includelimit[height=20cm]{example-image}
\includelimit[scale=0.5]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This shows how to replace \includegraphics with the new version.  I do NOT recommend this since it no longer supports all the keywords.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\let\oldincludegraphics=\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]% will get bad results with [rotate]
{\bgroup
  \sbox0{\oldincludegraphics{#2}}%
  \sbox1{\oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \dimen1=\ht0
  \ifdim\ht1<\dimen1 \dimen1=\ht1\fi
  \dimen2=\wd0
  \ifdim\wd1<\dimen2 \dimen2=\wd1\fi
  \oldincludegraphics[width=\dimen2, height=\dimen1]{#2}%
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\oldincludegraphics{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=20cm]{example-image}
\includegraphics[height=20cm]{example-image}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution works, thanks! However I wonder if it's possible to add a new option to `\includegraphics` like did some answers to this other question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/446660