# how to make a line between two rows in table? (when no space between strings)

Tags: tables, line-breaking, line-spacing

I use longtabu package to build table, when I use \\ to separate every line, it is ok, see below

```
\begin{center}

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|X[1 , p ] |X[1 , p ] | X[2 , p ]| X[2 , p ]|X[1 , p ]|X[1 , p ]|}

\caption{A simple longtabu example}\\

\hline

\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} & \textbf{E} & \textbf{F}  \\

\hline

\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{6}{c}%

{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\

\hline

\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} & \textbf{E} & \textbf{F}  \\

\hline

\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{6}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\

\endfoot

\hline

\endlastfoot



ab&cd&ef&gh&ij&kq\\ab&cd&ef&gh&ij&kq\\ab&cd&ef&gh&ij&kq\\\end{longtabu}\end{center}\end{document}
```

[image]

But if i use \hline or \hline\, like below, the complie always show error

```
ab&cd&ef&gh&ij&kq\hline\ab&cd&ef&gh&ij&kq\hline\ab&cd&ef&gh&ij&kq\hline\\end{longtabu}\end{center}\end{document}
```

OR

```
ab&cd&ef&gh&ij&kq\hlineab&cd&ef&gh&ij&kq\hlineab&cd&ef&gh&ij&kq\hline\end{longtabu}\end{center}\end{document}
```

OR \\\hline

```
ab&cd&ef&gh&ij&kq\\\hlineab&cd&ef&gh&ij&kq\\\hlineab&cd&ef&gh&ij&kq\\\hline\end{longtabu}\end{center}\end{document}
```

looks like this

[image]

The reason I write them together without any space is, I have a program to create table, the program use strings to create table.

I want to have a line between each row in the table, how to do it? either \hline or \hline\ doesnot work, for example \hline maybe read as \hlineab...

Comment: You must use ` \\ ` before a `\hline` command can be written! (or better, use `\tabularnewline`, if available!)

Comment: We can't not help about the program of course

Comment: \\\hline does not work too, the program has no problem, i just can not write a correct latex format to correctly create the table

Comment: Try `\\ \hline`

Comment: Off-topic comment: There is a question by you, having two answers, which both seem to fit your request - consider accepting one of them, before piling up other questions ;-) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194517/how-to-add-a-logo-in-every-page-without-any-margin

Comment: In the first example you have a `\ab` and in the second and third you have `\hlineab`. Change these to `ab` and `\hline ab`, respectively, and it should work.

Comment: Thank you!  I just fixed the problem, the answer is, first break the line: "\\", second draw a line: "\hline", third add a space:" "

Comment: The question could be solved by comments

Comment: It is not off-topic someone needs to write an answer. Please don't close all questions, this place started to look like SO

Comment: Simply you could play around this by inserting two braces after `\hline` as follows:

    `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{tabu}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{longtabu}{cccccc}\hline{}ab&cd&ef&gh&ij&kq\\\hline{}ab&cd&ef&gh&ij&kq\\\hline{}ab&cd&ef&gh&ij&kq\\\hline{}\end{longtabu}\end{document}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When building tables, the `\hline` command at the very beginning of a row: this means just after the `\begin{tabular}{<column-spec>}` line to come before the first row or immediately after `\\` for the other rows.

(La)TeX commands are made up of the escape character (`\`), a series of letters up to the first non-letter *or* the escape character (`\`) followed by one non-letter. Following these rules, `\hlineab` is a separate command name from `\hline`: both are made up of the escape sequence followed by letters. Thus your system for building your table needs to include *something* after `\hline` to separate it from `ab`. The usual case would simply to be to include a space here

```
\\ \hline ab
```

If for some reason that is not possible, adding an empty group will also do the job

```
\\ \hline{}ab
```

(This latter trick is also used to stop TeX skipping spaces after a command: not relevant here but does show up for example when writing for example `\LaTeX{} is a document preparation system`: try without the braces and see the effect.)

Comment: I already answered this in my comment above. Why don't I see up-votes?

Comment: @AboAmmar I don't follow. I'm happy to remove my answer if you want to post one instead, but comments don't have the same 'status' as answers for the StackExchange back-end. So while a comment can get votes, you don't get any 'reputation' for it and it doesn't mark the question as having an answer.

Comment: No, you shouldn't remove it since more readers can see the answer rather than comments. We aim at the benefit of the site users.