# How to put something on a page without disturbing the main vertical list?

Tags: spacing, positioning, page-breaking

I'd like to put something on an arbitrary place on a page.  I'm using

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  ...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

inside `\nointerlineskip\vbox to 0pt{\vss ...}\nointerlineskip`.  However, this messes up my MVL (if this occurs at a pagebreak, it seems that some unwanted vertical skip gets inserted).

Unfortunately, I can't come up with an MWE at the moment; but maybe someone just knows what I could do, in vertical mode, to put something somewhere on the page (preferably using the `tikz` trick), without messing up the page breaks?  (I need it in a class, where it is turned on or off, depending on a class option, and it has to have the same pagebreaks in either case.)

Comment: I have no idea if it works, but Komascript has a new module `scrlayer-scrpage`, which gives you the possibility to define different layers on the page, see chapter 16 in the manual.

Comment: The color package tries hard to add colour specials without messing up spacing and basically fails. To do it properly in full generality needs something like the latex3 xgalley code which takes full control of the MVL and doesn't allow any vskip or box etc to add to it directly, of course it's incompatible with everything

Comment: do you need it to be in the main list between items that appear adjacent or (simpler) can you have it overlayed by coordinates in the output routine over or under the main content?

Comment: Does this question help?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page