# Insert something that starts a page without affecting vertical spacing

Tags: spacing, positioning

This question is similar to the unanswered [How to put something on a page without disturbing the main vertical list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205123/87678) but (very slightly) more tightly defined.

I want to put a picture in the background of a page using `eso-pic` and `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*`.

Now, by default this page won't be output unless there is actually something on it.

I want it to show up when the page is empty and when the page contains content, but without knowing beforehand which case is wanted.

I can't just insert `\null` because this messes with the main vertical list and things like `\section` will then be at the wrong place at the top of the page.

Is there anything I can do or any work around?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageCenter{%
    \makebox(0,0){\includegraphics{example-image.pdf}}}}
% <- insert something that doesn't mess with vertical spacing but causes the
%    page to be output.
% <- possible further content (e.g., \section{...}) or possibly no content.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I will delete my above comments. Since your MWE did not have an `\section` or other code, I did not test it that way.

Comment: @RobtAll, no worries. The MWE is for the case with no content, but does include `\section` in the comments. (And to be fair, I mentioned `\null` in the question.)

Comment: did you try `\ifvmode\leavevmode\fi`

Comment: @touhami, this doesn't work. Extra vertical space is still inserted 
 before `\section`.

Comment: you can wrap it in `\AtEndDocument`?

Comment: @touhami, actually... that might just work with some tweaks!

Comment: Are there any side effects in putting `\null` in `\AtEndDocument`? Seems to work OK. I'll accept it as an answer if you post it.