# Wrong \href anchor location

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref

I use `hyperref` and `pgf` packages.

I need `pgf` to include and position an image:

```
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2, -2.4)}{
    \pgfbox[left,base]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{\@universitylogo}
    }
}

\href{http://www.example.com}{www.example.com}   % Shows link with broken anchor
```

But after each `\pgfbox[left,base]{}` call the `\href` anchor moves lower and lower below the link title. Any ideas how to fix the anchor?

Here is minimal example to demonstrate the broken `\href` anchor:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \pgfputat{\pgfxy(-1.3, -2.1)}{\pgfbox[left,base]{
      \includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{img/sun}}}
  \pgfputat{\pgfxy(10.9, -2.0)}{\pgfbox[left,base]{
      \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{img/moon}}}

  \parbox[b]{0.5\textwidth}{
     \centering \large\bf
     My University \\
     Institute of Science and Technology \\
     C O U N T R Y
  } 

\vskip 1cm
\href{http://www.example.com}{www.example.com}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: Are you using the raiselinks option?

Comment: No. Just tried setting it to ```true|false```, but no effect.

Comment: Never mind.  I presume this whole thing is sitting inside an \href command.  Perhaps you you put the \href inside the \pgfbox instead.

Comment: Nope, the ```\href``` and ```\pgfputat``` are in the same block.

Comment: Do you need to use this lowlevel commands instead of regular TikZ syntax ?

Comment: @percusse I don't need. But I simply don't know how to use TikZ. Someone suggested me to use this lowlevel code snippet for image positioning.

Comment: I can imagine. Can you extend your example to a real use case? I have some sort of an idea what your intention is but it's best if you just describe it.

Comment: I want to have logos on top left and top right corners and post the link somewhere on the same page. I have added working example.

Comment: I assume any alternative the reproduces the output without the `\href` problem is okay.

Comment: @Werner Yes, since the link is clickable and looks like url. I tried using other ```hyperref``` package commands, such as ```\url```, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very mild alternative that provides the output you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx,hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}m{.2\linewidth}Xm{.2\linewidth}@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
    \large\bfseries
    My University \par
    Institute of Science and Technology \par
    C O U N T R Y &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b} \\ \\[1cm]
    &
    \href{http://www.example.com}{www.example.com}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The `m`-column specification is similar to a `p`-column, but vertically centres its contents (supplied by the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) which is loaded by [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx)).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very nice workaround! But the question remains: is it possible to put an image anywhere on the page without breaking the ```hyperref``` anchors?

Comment: @niekas: Yes, you can place an image anywhere on the page. See [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169808/5764)

Answer (score 0):

I came here because I have had the same issue with `moderncv` when I would want to keep link clickable and put a logo. `pgfbox` it's clearly incompatible with `hyperref` if you don't use it, the link anchor is again at the right place. However, you can't get rid of it, because your images will become float (in my opinion), yielding an incorrect alignment.

I found a working solution, from Werner's link in comments where the initial author was Peter Grill : (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169836/125774). Amazing solution! You can once again use coordinates to place anythings.

[image: MWE]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand*{\BottomLeftX}{1.0in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin}%
\newcommand*{\BottomLeftY}{\paperheight-1.0in-\voffset-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\textheight}%
\newcommand*{\AbsolutePosition}[4][]{%
    % #1 = tikz options
    % #2 = x (from south west corner of page
    % #3 = y
    % #4 = text
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, ultra thick]
        %\draw [shift={(#2,#3)},#1]  (current page.south west) circle (2pt) 
        \draw [#1]  ($(current page.south west) + (\BottomLeftX,\BottomLeftY) + (#2,#3)$)  
                node[above right] {#4};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \AbsolutePosition{8.9cm}{17.5cm}{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \AbsolutePosition{0.9cm}{17.5cm}{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
  \parbox[b]{0.5\textwidth}{
     \centering \large\bf
     My University \\
     Institute of Science and Technology \\
     C O U N T R Y
  } 
\vskip 1cm
\href{http://www.example.com}{www.example.com}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```