# How to place edge-to-edge image across top of page?

Tags: graphics, backgrounds

I have a patterned background vector image that I'd like to place across the top of one page of my multipage document (a report if it matters).

The image is not the full size of the page, so what I'd like to do is scale it so that it is edge-to-edge from the left to the right, flush with the top edge (e.g. a bit like how the image on [this page](http://www.freepik.com/free-vector/grunge-abstract-background_762742.htm) looks). The rest of the page contents would be laid out as if the background image wasn't there.

How would I be able to place this image without having to pull in some very heavy weight packages?

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207332/make-picture-horizontally-fill-out-page-and-stay-at-top

Comment: Hi Steve. Thanks. Let me see if that question is similar.

Comment: Steven, the answer posted in that question doesn't seem to work. The image is in the PDF file but it is not flushed against the sides & top. I'm compiling with pdflatex. Do you know why?

Comment: What document class are you using?  I could foresee some issues if it is beamer.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way is using the [background](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package. Hopefully, this does not count as "heavy weight":)

Here's how I would do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{mwe}
\backgroundsetup{placement=top,
  contents={\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2truemm]{example-image-a}}
}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

and this is what this produces:

[image]

You can scale, trim, crop, .. the image using the option of the [graphicx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package.

Comment: I'd like to suggest the following modifications to your code: to use the `firstpage=true` package option (to guarantee that the image appears only on the first page, as required) and setting `scale=1` and `width=\paperwidth`; something like this `\usepackage[firstpage=true]{background}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{mwe}
\backgroundsetup{placement=top,nodeanchor=north west,
  scale=1,contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
}`

Comment: Ah, I misread the OP's question; since the image is to appear on just one page, but not necessarily the first one, it's better to use `\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{mwe}
\backgroundsetup{placement=top,nodeanchor=north west,
  scale=1,contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
}`
 and then say `\BgThispage` at some place on the one page which should receive the image.