# Make image cover exactly upper half of page

Tags: graphics, positioning, minipage, covers

**Problem:**

Trying to fit an image to the upper half of a page but without success.

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
\documentclass[export]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{{./figures/},{./chapters/}}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}[!t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{chapter1.jpg}
    \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

To make the image cover exactly the upper half of the page, starting from the top-left corner.

Comment: See this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207332/make-picture-horizontally-fill-out-page-and-stay-at-top and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235587/graphics-against-page-border

Comment: Excellent, that solved it!

Answer (score 1):

There are several packages that permit to use *absolute positioning* (see [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page/169831#169831) or its linked questions)

What follows is a solution made with `TikZ`. It needs two compilations to obtain the correct result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=.5\paperheight]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]