# Add some vertical text on the margin of document?

Tags: vertical-alignment, margins, urls

I like to put url in the left/right margin and align it vertically like arXiv (see figure below).

[image: A sample figure]

Here is a MWE:

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}

    \lipsum

    \end{document}
```

Comment: And the MWE? Where is it?

Comment: Related Question: [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page/169831#169831).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way would be to use the `background` package:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[all]{background}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetBgContents{\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}}% Set contents
\SetBgPosition{current page.west}% Select location
\SetBgVshift{-1.0cm}% Add vertical shift (results in a shift in x direction due to rotation)
\SetBgOpacity{1.0}% Select opacity
\SetBgAngle{90.0}% Select rotation of logo
\SetBgScale{2.0}% Select scale factor of logo

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution does not work with links to labels.

Comment: How can I center it perfectly, especially on the y-axis? Any commands for that?

Comment: @Vladimir: Updated solution. Will update image once the [Image Uploader Using Random Image](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8734/4301) problem is resolved.

Comment: @PeterGrill thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I usually use a combination of `eso-pic`, `graphicx` and `rotating` as it is easy to adjust in terms of location, angle and size.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{eso-pic, rotating, graphicx}

\AddToShipoutPicture{\put(30,200){\rotatebox{90}{\scalebox{3}{Examiners copy}}}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[4]

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: This solution works with links to labels.

Comment: Use `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*` if you want the mark only once. Also `AddToShipoutPicture` seems depreciated and repalced by `AddToShipoutPictureBG` and `AddToShipoutPictureFG`