# Move logo higher above the title?

Tags: graphics

I have a logo above my title. However, it is taking too much space, causing there to be very little content on the first page. How can I move everything up?

I definitely can reduce the margin, but I do want to limit the effect with this 1st page only.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\title{
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{logo}\\
The Title
}
\author{%
  The Author
}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use the `eso-pic` package to position it freely on the page. Here's an example: http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=2914

Comment: Your MWE places the `\includegraphics` (logo??) below the author, not above the title.  So what is it you really want to accomplish?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Corrected. Thanks for pouting it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, I `\smash`ed the graphic, so that it appears to TeX to take up zero vertical space.  If you need it higher, let me know.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\title{
\leavevmode\smash{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{logo}}\\
The Title
}
\author{%
  The Author
}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is so awesome! Exactly what I want! Thank you, sir! I would also very much appreciate if you could **very briefly** explain what the magic `smash` does, and why it yields a "just right" spacing from the top edge.

Comment: @FarticlePilter  `\smash` doesn't alter it's argument, but convinces LaTeX that its vertical dimension is 0cm.  Therefore, the bottom edge of the image is located the same place the bottom edge of a (for example) where a period would sit (if you replaced your image with a `.`).  If the image were too tall, it could run off the top of the page (glad that didn't happen in your case).  So in this instance, the "correct" spacing was a bit fortuitous.  From that point, the `\\ ` inserts a linefeed so that `The Title` is on a new line below the image.

Comment: @FarticlePilter  Another apprach would be to place the image independently on the page, using something like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page/169831#169831, and then using your `\title` macro with just a text argument.