# Is it possible to store the height and width of an imported document in variables and adjust the page to fit it (reverse-engineering layouts)?

Tags: geometry, pdfpages, paper-size, dimensions

For example, let's say that I use the `pdfpages` package and import a PDF. Is there any way (without using an external scripting language like Python) to access the dimensions of the PDF? Can I pass those dimensions to the `geometry` package?

I would like a simple way to create a document output that

- fits page geometry to an inputted file precisely
- draws a grid over the entire document (see [How can I make a perfect page grid that fits my page for measuring purposes in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229279/how-can-i-make-a-perfect-page-grid-that-fits-my-page-for-measuring-purposes-in-t))

The grid overlay should be drawn efficiently using these new dimensions (variables grabbed from input should be passed to TikZ), because I don't want to just make the grid big enough to cover any likely paper size (not very efficient for inputs with smaller dimensions).

## Purpose

This is useful for reverse-engineering PDF templates/layouts (e.g. from InDesign) or images. By reverse-engineering, I mean that I can easily design precise layouts with TikZ's page coordinates.

## Code

In this example, I commented out a `pdfinput` in the body. I want to grab the pdf dimensions at that point and create `\setpaperwidth` and `\setpaperheight` macros that set the `\inputwidth` and `\inputheight` variables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand\inputwidth{5.5in}  % <- set from input
\newcommand\inputheight{8.5in} % <- set from input

\usepackage[%
paperwidth=\inputwidth,  
paperheight=\inputheight,  
verbose,             % show the values of the parameters in the log file
]{geometry}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz} % Support for drawing grid
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}
\usepackage{atbegshi} % Add support for the showgrid overlay
\newcommand{\showgrid}{%
  \AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBoxForeground{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        [
          overlay,
          remember picture,
          inner sep=0pt,
          outer sep=0pt,
          minor line/.style={help lines, draw=black!50, on background layer},
          major line/.style={help lines, draw=black},
          major number/.style={font=\fontsize{3}{5}\selectfont\bfseries},
          minor number/.style={font=\fontsize{1}{2}\selectfont},
        ]
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\xmaxstep{\paperwidth/1mm}% calculate needed steps in x direction
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\ymaxstep{\paperheight/1mm}% calculate needed steps in y direction
        \foreach \step in {0,1,...,\xmaxstep} {
          \pgfmathsetmacro\gridlineconfig{ifthenelse(equal(int(mod(\step,10)),0),"major line","minor line")}%
          \draw [\gridlineconfig] ($(current page.north west) + (\step mm,0)$) -- ($(current page.south west) + (\step mm,0)$);
        }
        \foreach \step in {0,1,...,\ymaxstep} {
          \pgfmathsetmacro\gridlineconfig{ifthenelse(equal(int(mod(\step,10)),0),"major line","minor line")}%
          \pgfmathsetmacro\numberconfig{ifthenelse(equal(int(mod(\step,10)),0),"major number","minor number")}%
          \draw [\gridlineconfig] ($(current page.north west) - (0,\step mm)$) -- ($(current page.north east) - (0,\step mm)$);
          \node [anchor=north,\numberconfig] at ($ (current page.north west) + (\step mm,0) $) {\step};
          \node [anchor=west,\numberconfig] at ($ (current page.north west) - (0,\step mm) $) {\step};
        }
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
  }%
}
\pagenumbering{gobble} % Remove Page Numbers (without fancyhdr)
\begin{document}
\showgrid
\null
%\includepdf[noscale]{pdffile.pdf} % <- Grab dimensions here
\end{document}
```

Comment: `pdfinfo` can show you the dimension of a PDF file.

Comment: @egreg I assume that is not the same as this `pdfinfo` http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26531/13552

Comment: No, I mean the command line utility named `pdfinfo`.

Comment: Well, you can `\includegraphics` the first page into a box and measure the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `graphicx`'s `\includegraphics` to store a page of the document and measure it:

```
\newsavebox{\measurebox}
\newlength{\measuredwidth}
\newlength{\measuredheight}
\newcommand\measureimage[2][1]{%
    \savebox{\measurebox}{\includegraphics[page=#1]{#2}}%
    \setlength{\measuredwidth}{\wd\measurebox}%
    \setlength{\measuredheight}{\ht\measurebox}%
    \savebox{\measurebox}{}%
    }

...

\measureimage[2]{myfigure} % measures the 2nd page of the file.

\showthe\measuredwidth % shows the width
\showthe\measuredheight % shows the height
```

After issuing `\measureimage[pagenumber]{filename}`, the width and height of the image are stored in `\measurewidth` and `\measuredheight`. The default page number is `1`. Just remember that doing this is not quite fast so you should use it only a small number of files (it wouldn't be good if you needed to measure each page separately).

Answer (score 1):

## Fit Page Dimensions to Input and Draw Grid Overlay

After experimenting with yo's answer, I found a way to achieve this with any PDF or image file input.

Given image `hike.png`:

- `identify -format "%wx%h\n" hike.png` -> 483x271
- `file hike.png`- > hike.png: PNG image data, 483 x 271, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced

[image]

Include in body with `\measureimage[1]{hike.png}`, which does the following:

1. Grab dimensions of `hike.png`
2. Reset paperwidth and paperheight for TikZ nodes
3. Reset pdfpaperwidth and pdfpaperheight for actual paper size output with `\eject`
4. Add image overlay using TikZ node
5. Apply grid over image (using `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight` for x and y max values) in 1 millimeter intervals.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[%
%paperwidth=\inputwidth,  % Unneeded
%paperheight=\inputheight,% Unneeded
verbose,             % show the values of the parameters in the log file
]{geometry}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz} % Support for drawing grid
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}
\usepackage{atbegshi} % Add support for the showgrid overlay
\newcommand{\showgrid}{%
  \AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBoxForeground{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        [
          overlay,
          remember picture,
          inner sep=0pt,
          outer sep=0pt,
          minor line/.style={help lines, draw=black!50, on background layer},
          major line/.style={help lines, draw=black},
          major number/.style={font=\fontsize{3}{5}\selectfont\bfseries},
          minor number/.style={font=\fontsize{1}{2}\selectfont},
        ]
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\xmaxstep{\pdfpagewidth/1mm}% calculate needed steps in x direction
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\ymaxstep{\pdfpageheight/1mm}% calculate needed steps in y direction
        \foreach \step in {0,1,...,\xmaxstep} {
          \pgfmathsetmacro\gridlineconfig{ifthenelse(equal(int(mod(\step,10)),0),"major line","minor line")}%
          \draw [\gridlineconfig] ($(current page.north west) + (\step mm,0)$) -- ($(current page.south west) + (\step mm,0)$);
        }
        \foreach \step in {0,1,...,\ymaxstep} {
          \pgfmathsetmacro\gridlineconfig{ifthenelse(equal(int(mod(\step,10)),0),"major line","minor line")}%
          \pgfmathsetmacro\numberconfig{ifthenelse(equal(int(mod(\step,10)),0),"major number","minor number")}%
          \draw [\gridlineconfig] ($(current page.north west) - (0,\step mm)$) -- ($(current page.north east) - (0,\step mm)$);
          \node [anchor=north,\numberconfig] at ($ (current page.north west) + (\step mm,0) $) {\step};
          \node [anchor=west,\numberconfig] at ($ (current page.north west) - (0,\step mm) $) {\step};
        }
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
  }%
}
\pagenumbering{gobble} % Remove Page Numbers (without fancyhdr)

\newsavebox{\measurebox}
\newlength{\measuredwidth}
\newlength{\measuredheight}

\newcommand\measureimage[2][1]{%
    \savebox{\measurebox}{\includegraphics[page=#1]{#2}}%
    \setlength{\measuredwidth}{\wd\measurebox}%
    \setlength{\measuredheight}{\ht\measurebox}%
    \savebox{\measurebox}{}%
    \paperwidth=\measuredwidth \paperheight=\measuredheight     % paper dimensions for TikZ page nodes
    \eject \pdfpagewidth=\measuredwidth \pdfpageheight=\measuredheight % set paper dimensions in XeLaTeX
    \tikz [overlay, remember picture] \node [anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics[page=#1]{#2}};
    \showgrid
    }

\begin{document}
\measureimage[1]{hike.png} % measures the 2nd page of the file.

%Height: \the\measuredwidth % shows the width of the paper 

%Width: \the\measuredheight % shows the height of the paper
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]