# Read PDF size to adjust size of next page

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, page

I am trying to read the size of a PDF file to adjust the size of the next page to the size of the figure.
I have had some success, but the figure is still not well adjusted. I could adjust this figure, but I want to automate the adjustment, as I have 150 figures to insert in the file.
I also need to add an extra height on the page, to place the caption of the figure.
Any suggestion?

```
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
    \setbox0 = \hbox{\includegraphics{01.pdf}}
    width = \the\wd0, height = \the\ht0

\newpage
%================================================================================
\eject \pdfpagewidth=\the\wd0 \pdfpageheight=\the\ht0

\begin{figure}
    \caption{<name picture>}
    \includegraphics{01.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt using `\igrgraph` command from [`incgraph`](https://ctan.org/pkg/incgraph) pacakge.

`\igrgraph{<text>}` automatically typesets `<text>` in a separate page with height and width the same of `<text>`, so you don't need to manually change page size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{incgraph}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
text on first page
\igrpage{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics{example-image}}%
  \begin{minipage}{\wd0}
    \captionof{figure}{figure on second page}
    \box0\relax
  \end{minipage}%
}
text on third page
\end{document}
```

This generates a three-page pdf, of which the second page is
[image]

Answer (score 0):

PARTIAL ANSWER

with the help of the answer below:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268919/134993

I write:

```
%---------------------------------------------------
    \newsavebox{\measurebox}
    \newlength{\measuredwidth}
    \newlength{\measuredheight}
    \newcommand\measureimage[2][1]{%
        \savebox{\measurebox}{\includegraphics[page=#1]{#2}}%
        \setlength{\measuredwidth}{\wd\measurebox}%
        \setlength{\measuredheight}{\ht\measurebox}%
        \savebox{\measurebox}{}%
    } %-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\measureimage[1]{01.pdf} % measures the 1nd page of the file.
    
\newpage
    
\newgeometry{left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm}
\eject \pdfpagewidth=\measuredwidth \pdfpageheight=\measuredheight

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics{01.pdf}
\caption{caption picture}
\end{figure}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

TO DO:
I still have to find out a way to insert a space below the figure to place the caption.

Any suggestions?

[image]