# Grid Lines on whole page for comparing spacing

Tags: graphics, arrays, article

I am building on my resume on latex and need fine grid lines to compare spacing between sections and subsections.
You might need this info.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom = 0.6in,left = 0.56in,right = 0.56in,top = 0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newcommand{\xfilll}[2][1ex]{
\dimen0=#2\advance\dimen0 by #1
\leaders\hrule height \dimen0 depth -#1\hfill}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\raisebox{0.4ex}{\tiny$\bullet$}}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\cdot$}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
% \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}  % for underline
% \usepackage{sectsty}
% \sectionfont{\centering}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\sbt}{\,\begin{picture}(-1,1)(-1,-3)\circle*{2.5}\end{picture}\ }
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This question may be useful: [How can I make a perfect page grid that fits my page for measuring purposes in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229279/579)

Answer (score 8):

Welcome to TeX.SE! If I understood your question correctly, you would like to draw a grid in front of, or behind the normal document contents.

## Ready-made grid with `eso-pic`

Drawing a ready-made grid in the foreground or background is easy to do with the `eso-pic` package:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[grid, gridunit=mm, gridcolor=blue!40, subgridcolor=blue!20]{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: page 1]

---

[image: page 2]

The units available for the `gridunit` option are `mm`, `in`, `bp` and `pt`. You can additionally pass the `gridBG` option to `eso-pic` if you want it to draw the grid in the background.

## Manual grid with Ti*k*Z

Ti*k*Z provides simple and powerful tools to do this kind of thing too. Using Ti*k*Z requires a little more work, but provides much greater control over the output than one has with `eso-pic`. Several methods are possible; here, we'll use the `grid` operation in conjunction with the `current page` node (see *The Grid Operation* and *Referencing the Current Page Node – Absolute Positioning* in the [Ti*k*Z and PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), § 14.8 and § 17.13.2 of the manual for version 3.1.4a).

Following the request you made in a comment, here is an example with a rather fine grid (`step=0.5pt`) that will be laid in the background of the first page only—actually, wherever you decide to put the `tikzpicture`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,
                    help lines/.append style={line width=0.05pt}]
  \draw[help lines] (current page.south west) grid[step=0.5pt]
                    (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Zoom on the beginning of the first paragraph:

[image: Small part of first paragraph]

With the following code, the same grid will be colored in light blue and laid in the background of all pages:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,
                    help lines/.append style={line width=0.05pt,
                                              color=blue!10}]
  \draw[help lines] (current page.south west) grid[step=0.5pt]
                    (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: Small part of first paragraph]

Of course, it is possible to draw two grids on top of each other:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,
                    help lines/.append style={line width=0.05pt,
                                              color=blue!10},
                    major divisions/.style={help lines,line width=0.1pt,
                                            color=red!20} ]
  \draw[help lines] (current page.south west) grid[step=0.5pt]
                    (current page.north east);
  \draw[major divisions] (current page.south west) grid[step=5pt]
                         (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: Small part of first paragraph]

## Pointer to a related question

Note: you can find several complex answers based on Ti*k*Z or other techniques in [How can I make a perfect page grid that fits my page for measuring purposes in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229279/how-can-i-make-a-perfect-page-grid-that-fits-my-page-for-measuring-purposes-in-t).

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me a lot. I want the grid to be a more fine but using pt is not enough. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Please see the latest edit of my answer.