# Extend foldmarks of scrlttr2 document class to further pages

Tags: letters, scrlttr2

I am writing a longer letter using the `scrlttr2` document class which extends to multiple pages. I activated the foldmarks parameter in the class options.

However, the foldmarks do not reappear on the second and later pages. How can I extend the foldmarks to further pages than the first?

---

**EDIT:** As in esdd's comment, the post [Add marker lines in page margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246022/add-marker-lines-in-page-margin/246154#246154) provides a workaround.

Comment: See [Add marker lines in page margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246154/43317). But then you have to deactivate the `scrlttr2` foldmarks. If you need additional help, then please add a MWE (minimal working example) to your question.

Comment: did you try it : \usepackage{lettrine}

Comment: @esdd Thank you, I've included the link in the post as well. This works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class `scrlttr2` only supports foldmarks on the first page of the letter. They are put on the first page in the same way (using pseudo lengths) like the senders information, the address, the logo etc.

But you can load package `scrlayer-scrpage` and define new layers for the fold marks using their pseudo-lengths

```latex
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets automatically page style scrheadings
\DeclareNewLayer[%
  background,
  innermargin,
  oddpage,
  height=\useplength{tfoldmarkvpos}+.5\useplength{foldmarkthickness},
  hoffset=\useplength{foldmarkhpos},
  mode=picture,
  contents=\putLL{\rule{\useplength{tfoldmarklength}}{\useplength{foldmarkthickness}}}
]{tfoldmark}
\DeclareNewLayer[%
  clone=tfoldmark,
  height=\useplength{bfoldmarkvpos}+.5\useplength{foldmarkthickness},
  contents=\putLL{\rule{\useplength{bfoldmarklength}}{\useplength{foldmarkthickness}}}
]{bfoldmark}
\DeclareNewLayer[%
  clone=tfoldmark,
  height=.5\paperheight+.5\useplength{foldmarkthickness},
  contents=\putLL{\rule{\useplength{pfoldmarklength}}{\useplength{foldmarkthickness}}}
]{pfoldmark}
```

Then you have to add the layers to the page style(s) used on subsequent pages:

```latex
\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{tfoldmark,bfoldmark,pfoldmark}
%\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{tfoldmark,bfoldmark,pfoldmark}
```

Note that the first page of the letter uses page style `empty`.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets automatically page style scrheadings
% declare new layers for the fold marks on subsequent pages using their pseudo-lengths
\DeclareNewLayer[%
  background,
  innermargin,
  oddpage,
  height=\useplength{tfoldmarkvpos}+.5\useplength{foldmarkthickness},
  hoffset=\useplength{foldmarkhpos},
  mode=picture,
  contents=\putLL{\rule{\useplength{tfoldmarklength}}{\useplength{foldmarkthickness}}}
]{tfoldmark}
\DeclareNewLayer[%
  clone=tfoldmark,
  height=\useplength{bfoldmarkvpos}+.5\useplength{foldmarkthickness},
  contents=\putLL{\rule{\useplength{bfoldmarklength}}{\useplength{foldmarkthickness}}}
]{bfoldmark}
\DeclareNewLayer[%
  clone=tfoldmark,
  height=.5\paperheight+.5\useplength{foldmarkthickness},
  contents=\putLL{\rule{\useplength{pfoldmarklength}}{\useplength{foldmarkthickness}}}
]{pfoldmark}
% add the wanted fold marks to the layer page style(s) used on subsequent pages
\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{tfoldmark,bfoldmark,pfoldmark}
%\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{tfoldmark,bfoldmark,pfoldmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{address}
\opening{Hello}
\lipsum
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]