# Cover page with banner image, following text overlaps

Tags: graphics, positioning, covers

I am designing a newsletter. The cover page will have an edge-to-edge banner image at the top of the page. I will have images and text below that, which will be different each issue.

I don't know how to place the banner so that the following content will start below it, rather than placed on top. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\textblockorigin{0mm}{0mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{textblock}{16}(-0.25,0)
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}  
\end{textblock}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: Page with text overlapping banner image]

I've also tried the solution using everpage suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169831/3197) with similar results. I am aware of TikZ, but I don't understand it - maybe it would help here, but I'm not sure and there is a lot of documentation to work through to figure out if it might be useful.

What should I do to place an image across the entire page, absolutely positioned, and have subsequent content start below the image?

Comment: Have you considered using the `wallpaper` package to put a page-sized PDF into the background?

Comment: @ChristianLindig No. I don't know what that means. If the image is in the background, will I still have the same problem with the subsequent text being placed without regard to the location of the image?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem - `wallpaper` is indeed not a good idea as the foreground material is not aware of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach that might meet your needs.

***EDIT*** I have extended the code to cater for your desire to have the banner at the top of the sheet (but beware of any typos).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newlength{\mylen}
\setlength{\mylen}{\oddsidemargin}
\addtolength{\mylen}{1in} % = distance from paper edge to textblock

\newlength{\tlen} \setlength{\tlen}{\topmargin}
\addtolength{\tlen}{\headheight} \addtolength{\tlen}{\headsep}
\addtolength{\tlen}{1.15in} % final tweak for sheet top to textblock top

\begin{document}
\vspace*{-\tlen}
\noindent\hspace{-\mylen} \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}
\begin{multicols}{2}
The contents of your document now in two columns after the banner 
spanning the width of the page.

\blindtext
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I transfer a PDF file from my computer to show up in StackExchange?

Comment: This doesn't compile for me, I get a 'missing number, treated as zero' error

Comment: Found the problem, a missing \

Comment: This doesn't work, as the banner is not placed at the top of the page. I need it to be flush with the top, which is why I was using the `textpos` package to set the position absolutely.

Comment: `@Tyler` I have revised the example code so that the banner is placed at the top of the page.