# How I can decorate LaTeX wedding card with colors and watermark images?

Tags: graphics

I am creating a wedding card using `LaTeX`. But my card only have text, just like wedding card. Its very simple. How I can give nice look to this wedding card? How I can add colors and watermark image as background?

```js
 \documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
 \usepackage[cam,width=4truein,height=6truein,letter,center] {crop}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{calligra}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage{anysize}
 \marginsize{2cm}{2cm}{6.6cm}{1cm}

 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \begin{document}
  \crop
  \begin{center}
  {\sc \scriptsize Mr and Mrs sood Parents}\\
  {\calligra \small are pleased to announce the marriage of their
  daughter}\\
  {\sc \scriptsize Deb}\\
  {\calligra \small to}\\
  {\sc \scriptsize Napoleon}\\
  {\calligra \small son of}\\
  {\sc \scriptsize Mr and Mrs Dhiman}\\
  {\calligra \small on March 1,2016}\\
  {\calligra \small in the Las Vegas}\\
 \ \\
  {\calligra \small The pleasure of your company is requested}\\
  {\calligra \small at a celebration in their honor}\\
 \ \\
 \ \\
 \begin{tabular}{l|l}
 {\calligra\small Reception                 } & {\calligra\small   Open
House}\\
 \sc{\scriptsize Overpriced Reception Center} & \sc{\scriptsize
 Somebody's House}\\
 \sc{\scriptsize 775 East 1200 North        } &   \sc{\scriptsize    4321 West
 3540 North}\\
\sc{\scriptsize Las Vegas, Nevada          } & \sc{\scriptsize   Las
Vegas, Nevada}\\
\sc{\scriptsize March 1, 2016 } & \sc{\scriptsize Saturday,
March 4, 2016}\\
\sc{\scriptsize 7:05 p.m. to 9:09 p.m.     } & \sc{\scriptsize   6:59 p.m.
to 9:01 p.m.}\\
\end{tabular}\\
\ \\
\ \\
{\calligra \small The bride and groom are registered at}\\
{\calligra \small Deseret Industries}\\
\end{center}
```

output:
   [image]

Comment: `\sc` is outdated and should not be used and does not have an argument at all . Use `\scshape` for a global font change or `\textsc{foo}` for a locally limited one.

Comment: I don't think that this invitation needs any additional decoration. I would rather look for a nice sheet of (only lightly) colored paper. (just my two cents)

Comment: And `\sc` never did take an argument. It is a switch. `\sc{abc} def` does just the same as `\sc abc def`. Both are obsolete, of course, in LaTeX. You need to adjust the spacing after the first `p.m.` in each block. You want, for example, `7:05 p.m.\ to 9:09 p.m.`. Right now, the space is obviously too large.

Comment: Napoleon Dhimanite?

Answer (score 4):

Using my approach from [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page/169831#169831).  I show both how to make a full-page underlay, as well as inset underlays, using the syntax `\atxy{x-loc}{y-loc}{underlay}`

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
 \usepackage[cam,width=4truein,height=6truein,letter,center] {crop}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{calligra}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage{anysize}
 \marginsize{2cm}{2cm}{6.6cm}{1cm}

 \thispagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{everypage,graphicx}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddThispageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}
\atxy{0in}{6in}{\includegraphics[width=4in,height=6in]{example-image-A}}
\atxy{0.4in}{2.2in}{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1in]{example-image-B}}

 \begin{document}
  \crop
  \begin{center}
  {\sc \scriptsize Mr and Mrs sood Parents}\\
  {\calligra \small are pleased to announce the marriage of their
  daughter}\\
  {\sc \scriptsize Deb}\\
  {\calligra \small to}\\
  {\sc \scriptsize Napoleon}\\
  {\calligra \small son of}\\
  {\sc \scriptsize Mr and Mrs Dhiman}\\
  {\calligra \small on March 1,2016}\\
  {\calligra \small in the Las Vegas}\\
 \ \\
  {\calligra \small The pleasure of your company is requested}\\
  {\calligra \small at a celebration in their honor}\\
 \ \\
 \ \\
 \begin{tabular}{l|l}
 {\calligra\small Reception                 } & {\calligra\small   Open
House}\\
 \sc{\scriptsize Overpriced Reception Center} & \sc{\scriptsize
 Somebody's House}\\
 \sc{\scriptsize 775 East 1200 North        } &   \sc{\scriptsize    4321 West
 3540 North}\\
\sc{\scriptsize Las Vegas, Nevada          } & \sc{\scriptsize   Las
Vegas, Nevada}\\
\sc{\scriptsize March 1, 2016 } & \sc{\scriptsize Saturday,
March 4, 2016}\\
\sc{\scriptsize 7:05 p.m. to 9:09 p.m.     } & \sc{\scriptsize   6:59 p.m.
to 9:01 p.m.}\\
\end{tabular}\\
\ \\
\ \\
{\calligra \small The bride and groom are registered at}\\
{\calligra \small Deseret Industries}\\
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As noted by others, color is added with the `xcolor` package.  One can use `\textcolor{red}{text}` to limit the scope of the color change, or just `\color{red}` to change the color from that point forward in the document.

Comment: I like it that way, with the big "A" and the smaller "B".

Answer (score 3):

First version, trying to improve

You can use `\usepackage{xcolor}` and either the `\color{colourname}` command for the colors or `\textcolor{colourname}{text}`.

For the `watermark`, the `background` package can be used, having some options to control the opacity and position of the image. (I have used some simple options to get a fast result)

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
 \usepackage[cam,width=4truein,height=6truein,letter,center] {crop}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{calligra}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage{anysize}
 \usepackage{background}
 \usepackage{graphics}
 \marginsize{2cm}{2cm}{6.6cm}{1cm}


 \thispagestyle{empty}

  \backgroundsetup{scale=0.5,angle=0,opacity=0.6,position={16.5cm,-15.0cm},contents={\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{wedding-rings-2400px}}}

\begin{document}


  \crop
  \begin{center}
  {\scshape \color{blue} \scriptsize Mr and Mrs sood Parents}\\
  {\calligra \small are pleased to announce the marriage of their
  daughter}\\
  {\scshape \scriptsize Deb}\\
  {\calligra \small to}\\
  {\scshape \scriptsize Napoleon}\\
  {\calligra \small son of}\\
  {\scshape \scriptsize Mr and Mrs Dhiman}\\
  {\calligra \small on March 1,2016}\\
  {\calligra \small in the Las Vegas}\\
 \ \\
  {\calligra \small The pleasure of your company is requested}\\
  {\calligra \small at a celebration in their honor}\\
 \ \\
 \ \\
 \begin{tabular}{l|l}
 {\calligra\small Reception                 } & {\calligra\small   Open
House}\\
 \sc{\scriptsize Overpriced Reception Center} & \textsc{\scriptsize
 Somebody's House}\\
 \sc{\scriptsize 775 East 1200 North        } &   \textsc{\scriptsize    4321 West
 3540 North}\\
\sc{\scriptsize Las Vegas, Nevada          } & \textsc{\scriptsize   Las
Vegas, Nevada}\\
\sc{\scriptsize March 1, 2016 } & \sc{\scriptsize Saturday,
March 4, 2016}\\
\sc{\scriptsize 7:05 p.m. to 9:09 p.m.     } & \textsc{\scriptsize   6:59 p.m.
to 9:01 p.m.}\\
\end{tabular}\\
\ \\
\ \\
{\calligra \small The bride and groom are registered at}\\
{\calligra \small Deseret Industries}\\
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The image of the wedding rings is used from [OpenClipart](https://openclipart.org/detail/75829/wedding-rings)