# Formatting, designing an exam paper examiner's column

Tags: two-column

I am a teacher and i want to write a question paper to include a column similar to the one shown on the right, written examiner's column[image: Written Examiner only]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my answer at [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page/169831#169831)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage,stackengine}
\setstackgap{L}{11pt}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atEveryxy[3]{%
 \AddEverypageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}
\atEveryxy{7in}{1.8in}{\rule[-\textheight]{1pt}{\textheight}\quad\Longunderstack{ Examiner only}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]