# How do I change the vertical location of a line?

Tags: vertical-alignment

How do I change the vertical location of a line by specifying an absolute value measured from the top or bottom of the page? I know that the `vspace` command can put an arbitrary space, but it is always a relative value from the previous line.

Comment: Do you have other text on the page? Is it just a single line of text?

Comment: Yes. I have several paragraphs in the page.

Comment: You can easily specify an absolute position on the page using [`textpos`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) or even overlay it using [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) (or [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)). What should happen if the absolute placement overruns with the existing content on the page? ...or will you make sure that never happens?

Comment: [This is what you can do with `eso-pic`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dpqpt.png)...

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page