# Absolute positioning of pspicture

Tags: positioning, pstricks, pspicture, qrcode

I am using `pst-barcode` to create qr code on page.
I would like to be able to put a different qr code on every even page at the same place.
I have no clue how to enforce absolute location of pspicture.

- How to position it absolute with overlaying the text?
- How to enforce page number?

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{pst-barcode}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(1in,1in)
       \psbarcode{testestestse}{}{qrcode}
     \end{pspicture}
  \end{document}
  ```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I figured it out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,lipsum,xcolor}
\geometry{showframe,margin=1in}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\newcommand{\qrqr}{
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
  \AtTextLowerLeft{
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}
  {}
  {
  \begin{pspicture}(1in,1in)

     \psbarcode{\thepage}{}{qrcode}
   \end{pspicture}
  }
  }%
}%
}

\begin{document}
\AddEverypageHook{\qrqr}
\lipsum[3-56]
\end{document}
```