# Box with fixed position in page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins, boxes

I would like a custom "emptybox" whose height can be chosen, but whose width and position is always the same: I would like the boxes to always extend through the full width of the document (from the left margin to the right margin).

So far I have this command:

```
\newcommand{\emptybox}[1]{\framebox[\textwidth]{\rule[-1em]{0cm}{#1}}}
```

But the problem is that the position of the box depends on where I call it. For instance if I use `\emptybox` inside an `enumerate`, the box will appear too much to the right.

Feel free to suggest a command not based on the one I gave, which does not do the job anyway. Thanks!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want a box that has the width `\linewidth`, starts at the left margin but the vertical  position may vary still?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: No answer with stacking boxes on top of other boxes? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It is the exception that proves the rule.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Correct. StevenB.Segletes: thank you for the link, but ideally I would like an explicit solution :p. David Carlisle's answer looks good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\emptybox}[1]{\par
\noindent
\hspace*{-\@totalleftmargin}\framebox[\textwidth]{\rule[-1em]{0cm}{#1}}%
\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


zzz
\emptybox{1cm}

\begin{itemize}
\item aaaa\emptybox{2pt}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item zzzzz\emptybox{40pt}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```