# How can I centre a block of text on a page, ignoring everything else on it?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm attempting to create text for an envelope. The sender is in the top-left corner, and the recipient should be centred vertically and horizontally with respect to the edges of the paper. That is, the presence of the sender  should not change the vertical alignment of the recipient.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[papersize={110mm,220mm},landscape,margin=5mm,twoside=false]{geometry}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

If undeliverable, please return to:

Joe Citizen

12345 Foo St

Bar BAZ 67890

\huge
RECIPIENT LINE 1

RECIPIENT LINE 2

RECIPIENT LINE 3

\end{document}
```

How can I vertically centre the `RECIPIENT` lines with respect to the entire page? The block itself should be centred, but text within it should be left justified.

Comment: Perhaps this question would give you several options: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `center` and `\vspace*{\fill}`; for the addressee, it's better to use `tabular`, so to get left alignment in the respective rows. For the return address, use a zero height box.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[
  papersize={110mm,220mm},
  landscape,
  margin=5mm,
  twoside=false
]{geometry}

\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\topskip{0pt}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\parbox[t][0pt]{\textwidth}{
  \vspace{0pt}% to set the reference point
  \raggedright
  If undeliverable, please return to:\\
  Joe Citizen\\
  12345 Foo St\\
  Bar BAZ 67890
}

\vspace*{\fill}

\begin{center}
\huge
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
Joe Citizen\\
12345 Foo St\\
Bar BAZ 67890
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\vspace*{\fill}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This mostly works, but `\vspace{0pt}` creates an additional margin at the top, so all the text is shifted down.

Comment: @Sparhawk Use `\vspace{-\ht\strutbox}`

Comment: This removes the top margin, but the text is still not vertically centred. I measure the gap above the recipient block to be ~9% larger than the gap below. In comparison, the `tikz` solution is much more precise.

Comment: @Sparhawk You probably want to set `\topskip` to zero

Comment: That also shifts the sender up. It's most evident if I set `margin=0mm`, then the sender runs off the top of the page.

Comment: @Sparhawk I don't know what your purpose is: does the set of postal rules you have to comply require centering of the address block? Anyway, I modified the code to show how to use `\topskip`.

Comment: Haha, no nothing like that. It started off as an exercise in making a template, then I got… uh… obsessive about alignment. Thanks, that works perfectly now.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `tikz` for that:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[papersize={110mm,220mm},landscape,margin=5mm,twoside=false]{geometry}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

If undeliverable, please return to:

Joe Citizen

12345 Foo St

Bar BAZ 67890
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (current page.center)
        {\huge\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
            RECIPIENT LINE 1\\
            RECIPIENT LINE 21\\
            RECIPIENT LINE 3
        \end{tabular}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but I find I have to `pdflatex` twice. Is that just something to do with tikz?

Comment: @Sparhawk yes, this is because `tikz`'s positioning option `current page.center` might need two runs to determine the needed shift to actually hit the center.

Comment: Pretty close, but the top gap is 4% shorter than the bottom gap, when I set `margin=0mm`. Probably good enough, but I wonder why the slight discrepancy.

Comment: @Sparhawk honestly I have no clue. Perhaps because those are all uppercase letters. Try with an `\fbox` around the tabular with `\fboxsep=-\fboxrule` before the `\fbox`. This way you could check for the discrepancy correctly.