# Typesetting a death annoucement

Tags: tikz-pgf

In some countries, death announcements are typeset as follows. There is a text, that is subjected to the usual typographic rules and the text is surrounded by a thick black border that leaves no white space.

Here is a quick try on half an A4 page.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[papersize={210mm,148.5mm},margin=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[coordinate,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (current page.north west)  (nw) {} ;
\node[coordinate,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (current page.south east)  (se) {} ;
\node[coordinate,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (current page.north east)  (ne) {} ;
\node[coordinate,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (current page.south west)  (sw) {} ;
\draw[line width=9mm] (nw) -- (ne) -- (se) -- (sw) -- (nw) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[t]{16cm}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\vfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like something more flexible, e.g., regarding margins with the black border. I have the feeling that what I have done is quite rough. Can you suggest something?

Comment: What you have done looks good in its approach, I think.  The other alternative is to set up page margins for the text, and to draw the black lines outside of the page margins.  That would eliminate the need for a `minipage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I had commented, the other alternative is to set up page margins to govern the text (optional argument to `geometry` package), and to then draw the black lines outside of the page margins. Here, I use the approach I used in [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page/169831#169831).

In the MWE, `\brdr` defines the thickness of the black border.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[papersize={210mm,148.5mm},margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,everypage}
\pagestyle{empty}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddThispageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}
% VERIFIED THAT SETTING \hoffset AND \voffset DO NOT BREAK SOLUTION.
%\hoffset=0.4in
%\voffset=0.2in
\newcommand\brdr{12pt}
\atxy{0in}{\paperheight}{\rule{\brdr}{\paperheight}}
\atxy{0in}{\brdr}{\rule{\paperwidth}{\brdr}}
\atxy{0in}{\paperheight}{\rule{\paperwidth}{\brdr}}
\atxy{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\brdr}{\paperheight}{\rule{\brdr}{\paperheight}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Vertical centering, if desired, can be achieved simply with `\vfill`s, in the manner of `\mbox{}\vfill\lipsum[1-2]\vfill\mbox{}`:

[image]

Comment: Yes, a solution avoiding a `minipage` is quite nice.

Answer (score 0):

ConTeXt can do this in a few lines.  The text block is centred, both horizontally and vertically.

```
\setuppagenumbering
  [location=none]

\definepapersize
  [obituary]
  [width=210mm,height=148.5mm]

\setuppapersize[obituary]

\setupbackgrounds
  [page]
  [frame=on,
   framecolor=black,
   rulethickness=10pt]

\starttext

\startstandardmakeup[align=middle]
  \input lorem
\stopstandardmakeup

\stoptext
```

[image]