# Place single glyph at a location on the page

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm looking to use LaTeX to emulate something like the typographic art that people make with letterpress printing. For me, this means that I'd like to be able to position a glyph arbitrarily at some `(x,y)` position on the page, with some rotation, and in an ideal world I'd like the glyph's center to be at `(x,y)` and also have it rotate about its center. I'm not so good at Tikz so I haven't tried it, but I guess that will probably be necessary? I'm open to using any packages.

Comment: look here: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfornament

Comment: you don't _need_ tikz of course, you could just use the graphics package from the core latex distribution.

Comment: Duplicate? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.south west)}]
\node at (10.23,10.35) {x};
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\glyph}[3]{%
\node[shift={#2}, rotate=#3] at (current page.south west) {#1};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\glyph{T}{(1,1)}{70}
\glyph{E}{(2,1.5)}{60}
\glyph{S}{(2.7,2)}{30}
\glyph{T}{(3,3)}{10}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: TEST glyphs]

Comment: works too...... +1