# Custom report title page designed in word

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles

how I can write this title page?

It was designed in ms word and I want to port it to latex.
I tried with `tikz`, but I can not place all elements in correct places.

*The LOGO is a png file; The cyan bar at the left side is only decoration and should be generated;*

[image]

Comment: While I provided an answer to your question, I would note that your question has not received positive feedback, because it shows no effort on your part.  While there is a lot of good help on this site, questioners are expected to provide code on what they have tried (a so-called Minimum Working Example).  Nonetheless, I welcome you to the site and hope you can find your niche here.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `\atxy` comes from my answer at [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page/169831#169831)  Note there is no use of `tikz`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}

% ORIGINAL DEFINITION
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddThispageHook{\hbox{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}}
% VERIFIED THAT SETTING \hoffset AND \voffset DO NOT BREAK SOLUTION.
%\hoffset=0.4in
%\voffset=0.2in
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\atxy{0in}{\paperheight}{\textcolor{cyan!40!green!30}{\rule{60pt}{\paperheight}}}
\atxy{70pt}{50pt}{\includegraphics[height=50pt,width=120pt]{example-image-a}}
\atxy{.96\paperwidth}{\paperheight}{\rotatebox{90}{\Huge\bfseries Lorem ipsum}}
\atxy{70pt}{\dimexpr-2pt+\paperheight}{Ver. 0.1.0}
\hfill\Longstack[r]{Lorem ipsum\\Lorem ipsum\\Lorem ...\\...ipsum}
\vspace{1.5in}

{\LARGE\noindent\bfseries
 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
\par}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image]