# Cloning university frontispiece with LaTex

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment

I'm writing my thesis with LaTex, but I'm not able to replicate my university frontispiece, can someone help me?

I've seen plenty of posts asking for this, but I just can't make it right.

Here is how it should look like.

[image: frontispiece]

Comment: What did you try? And what are your  difficulties?

Comment: You don't need to "clone" it.  You just need a high-resolution copy in digital form.  Then use `\includegraphics`, etc. to place it where you want on the page.  For example, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page

Comment: I've tried to imitate some other frontispiece in order to create my frontispiece, but all looks quite different to mine, and I've ended up with poor results.

Comment: Basically, any large organisation has a "press kit". Search for it, there you should be able to find the logos of your university in TeX-suitable formats (such as PDF or convertible to it vector graphics, such as EPS). In some cases you would also find the corporate font there. If it is used in the example (look at the fonts of its PDF version), use them too. Then mimic the layout of the page to your best ability, it should suffice.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes your solution is what I am doing at the moment. However, I thought it would be nice to do it in latex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to prepare a one page document, say `frontispiece.tex`, along the following lines:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{helvet}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\sffamily

\raggedright

\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{cafoscari}\hspace*{\fill}

\vspace{\fill}

\centering

{\fontsize{18}{24}\selectfont Master's Degree \\ in Typography\\}

\vspace{\fill}

{\fontsize{18}{24}\selectfont Final Thesis\\}

\vspace{\fill}

{\fontsize{24}{30}\bfseries Title\\}

\vspace{\fill}

\raggedright

\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont

\textbf{Supervisor}\\
Ch.\ Prof.\ Name Surname\\

\vspace{6ex}

\textbf{Assistant supervisor}\\
Ch.\ Prof.\ Name Surname\\

\vspace{6ex}

\textbf{Graduand}\\
Name Surname\\
Matricolation number\\
123456\\

\vspace{3ex}

\textbf{Academic Year}\\
2019/2020

\end{document}
```

Adjust the margins and the other figures to suit the model. I assume that the logo is available as a graphic file, use the proper name.

Once you are satisfied with the typesetting, you will have a PDF file that you can insert as the first page of your thesis with the help of `pdfpages`:

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

in the preamble and

```
\includepdf{frontispiece}
```

at the beginning of the document.

[image]