# How do I add a plus sign on the edge of the document?

Tags: formatting

My instructor told me to add a plus sign at the edge of my title page and Im not so sure on how to do that. The blue mark is where the + sign is going to be.
[image]

And the codes for my title page is:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=40mm]{HH.png} \hspace{8.2 cm} {\large\textmd{Datum: 2020-10-07}}
\end{figure} 

{\large\textmd{MTACI20h}}
\hspace{3.2cm} \large{\textmd{Handledare: Andreas Olsson}}
\vspace{0.1\textheight} 

\centering
    \vspace{1.5cm}
    \huge{\textsc{Laboration - tyngdpunkt}} \\
    \Large{\textsc{Fysik grundkurs}}
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: This question might help, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page

Comment: Margin paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}


 \begin{titlepage}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=40mm]{HH.png} \hfill {\large\textmd{Datum: 2020-10-07}}%hspace{8.2 cm}
\end{figure}

{\large\textmd{MTACI20h}}
\hfill\large{\textmd{Handledare: Andreas Olsson}}%\hspace{3.2cm}
\vspace{0.1\textheight}

\centering
    \vspace{1.5cm}
\makebox[1.05\linewidth][r]{\color{blue}\huge\bfseries +}\medskip\\
    \huge{\textsc{Laboration - tyngdpunkt}} \\
    \Large{\textsc{Fysik grundkurs}}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect.

Comment: @Bernard can you kindly share reason for `1.05\linewidth` instead of page width or hfill

Comment: It was to have the + sign slightly in the right margin. Just a trial and error to get something similar to what seems to be in the O.P. image.