# Package alternatives to textpos

Tags: polyglossia, arabic, bidi, textpos

It seems like `textpos` package doesn't play nice with `bidi` at all. I had to set `\textblockorigin{-430pt,0pt}` to get my text showing inside the page.

However, moving from one machine to another, I can't get the same compilation results.

Is there an alternative to package `textpos`?

Comment: Maybe something here?? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page

Comment: I"m afraid I don't have enough experience of RTL text to have a reasonable chance of debugging this problem myself (so I'd be interested in patches!)

Comment: Have you tried pgf/tikz?

Comment: @HasanZakeri, actually yes. That is what I ended up doing. Yet I am always afraid that would break as well just like `textpos` did after an update.

Comment: @NormanGray I just did a TeXLive update and had to remove the shifted position of the coordinates I introduced previously. Now it is working fine.