# Replicating a document format

Tags: tables, content-replication

Do you have an idea how to make a document such as the one in the link below? You can disregard what's written on the document.

[Link to Example Document](http://psihologija-ffbl.com/predmeti/opsta_psihologija/uvod_u_psihologiju.pdf)

[image]

Comment: I'd say with three `tabularx` environments. It also requires the `graphicx` package to include the logos, `xcolor` with option `[table]`. That's about all.

Comment: Do you have a blank stencil of the document and your goal is to fill it in?  Or are you hoping to create that stencil from scratch?

Comment: I'm hoping to create it from scratch. This one is done in Word. I can easily open it in Word and replace the fields but my goal is to create a Latex file.

Comment: If you have an approved fixed-style blank form that can be imported as a graphic, then an approach like this, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108374/how-can-i-construct-a-page-layout-with-framed-boxes, can be used to fill it in via LaTeX

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Everything, what is written on light blue faces (and maybe even those on dark blue) seems to have the function of an section or similar.  So, that seems to me as if it was constant text, that will not change.

The text in the white spaces seems to be variable text.

In the case, that my assumptions are correct, you can of course define some LaTeX-variables to be filled with the portions of the varying text.  Than you need to define a command or environment, wich will produce the table and fill in the contents of the before defined variables.

It should be easy.

In the meantime: here is my MWE.

Normally, I would put the definitions in a stylefile of its own.  In that case, you don't need the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

I defined some internal variables, e.g. `\course@title`.  The `@` makes them unusable in normal documents.  Using the `@` in the filename makes the variable name safe.  You won't define a second variable in your document just by accident.

I also defined user space commands, to manipulate the contents of the variables.

I also defined variables for the name of those parts of the text, which don't change, i.e. constant texts used as section name.  If you are sure, that you never ever have to change this section names, you don't need to define those names in variables.  Just use the section names directly in the command.  But if there is a slight chance, that some or all of these section names may change, you are on the safe side.

Finally, I defined the command `\coursetable` (so I am not convinced, that this is really a good name for the macro.   You have been warned.) which will do the typesetting for us.

By putting all the content in one macro, you are free, to fill your variables in whatever order you like.  It doesn't matter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}


%% Some new column declarations
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

%% Dont use indent here!
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%% maybe we need a uniqe skip:
\newlength{\myskip}\setlength{\myskip}{4ex}

%% Define some variables
\makeatletter
\def\course@title{}
\def\course@institute{Institute for Typography}
\def\course@teacher{}
%% This time with a default
\def\course@term{Summer2017}
\def\course@content{The course will explain the content of the course}
%% Define also the section names
\def\course@institutename{Institute}
\def\course@titlename{Course}
\def\course@teachername{Professor}
\def\course@termname{Semester}
\def\course@contentname{Contents}

%% Define the command, which will create the table right now.
\newcommand{\coursetable}{%
  % start a new page
  \clearpage%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  % Put in the Logos
  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}%
  \hfill%
  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}%
  \vspace{\myskip}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|C|C|}
    \hline
    \textbf{\course@titlename} & \textbf{\course@termname} \\
    \hline
    \course@title & \course@term \\
    \hline
    \textbf{\course@teachername} & \textbf{\course@institutename} \\
    \hline
    \course@teacher & \course@institute\\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}

  \vspace*{\myskip}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|L|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|C|}{\textbf{\course@contentname}}\\
    \hline
    \course@content\\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \vfill
  Signature: \hrulefill

}

%% Define user space commands to manipulate the internal variables 
\newcommand{\courseterm}[1]{\def\course@term{#1}}%
\newcommand{\coursetitle}[1]{\def\course@title{#1}}%
\newcommand{\courseinstitute}[1]{\def\course@institute{#1}}
\newcommand{\courseteacher}[1]{\def\course@teacher{#1}}
\newcommand{\coursecontent}[1]{\def\course@content{#1}}

%% Reserve the @-sign.
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%% The order, in which you define the variables, does not matter.
\coursetitle{Beautiful Concepts}
\courseteacher{Prof. Dr. Drofnats}
\coursecontent{We will discuss in deep, if good typography will enhace
every document of the world.  Therefore we will study two or three
examples} 

%% Now, build this table.    
\coursetable
\end{document}
```

This is the result.  Of course, it differs from your example, but I hope, it will show you the way to go for your document.

EDIT: ON thing I forgot to mention: have a look at the `xcolor`-package, to get those blue table rows.

[image]

Comment: While your text may be longer than a comment, it is not really an answer.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Just added an hopeful MWE.