# Using parskip increases tcbline spacing in tcolorbox?

Tags: tables, tcolorbox

There's a noticeable difference in spacing between tcblines and the tcblower in my tcolorbox table. I looked for a relevant spacing setting from tcb's documentation but couldn't find one, so I tried using [size=minimal], and noticed that the tcblines *still* had like 1em of spacing?

See [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419764/156666) for an image and code. What I ultimately want is that the spacings for tcblines and the tcblower would be the same.

Edit2: After creating the following example code, I discovered that by itself it works fine. It appears using the parskip package is what causes the difference in spacing.

Edit3: Solution added.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

    \newgeometry{left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.0cm, bottom=1.0cm}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced, space to upper,
    height fill, sharp corners,
    segmentation style=solid,
    colback=white,
    middle=0.1pc, boxsep=0.1pc]
        \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}
        {@{} >{\hsize=1.15\hsize}X >{\hsize=1.15\hsize}X >{\hsize=.7\hsize}X @{}}
            \textbf{Author}
            \vspace*{0.5pc}

            student name here
            &
            \textbf{Degree}
            \vspace*{0.5pc}

            degree programme here
            &
            \textbf{Time}
            \vspace*{0.5pc}

            2018
        \end{tabularx}
    \tcbline
        \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}
        {@{} >{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X @{}}
        \textbf{Thesis title}
        \vspace*{0.5pc}

        paper title here
        &
        99 pages

        9 pages of appendices
        \end{tabularx}
    \tcbline
        \textbf{Commissioned by}

        commissioner here
    \tcbline
        \textbf{Supervisor}

        supervisor here
    \tcbline
        \textbf{Abstract}

        \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
        \lipsum[3]
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pc}
    \tcblower
        \textbf{Keywords}

        keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, etc.
    \end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I honestly don't even understand what space you're referring to. The only noticeable different space is the one after `\lipsum[1]`, but from your description you seem to be talking about something else.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: I think that's the spacing that is referred too, which is caused by `height fill`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean the image from the answer, but the 2nd image from my question. See the "Keywords" row at the bottom, and how it almost touches the tcblower.

Comment: @TakingItCasual: Please post the compilable code that causes the issue -- apparently the answer there is not related to your current question

Comment: @TakingItCasual: No, please post the compilable document, not just fragments

Comment: you have `\textbf{Thesis title} \vspace*{0.5pc} paper title here & 99 pages 9 pages of appendices`, probably should be `\textbf{Thesis title} \vspace*{0.5pc} paper title here & 99 \vspace*{0.5pc} pages 9 pages of appendices`. observe diference in `\vspace*{0.5pc}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was parskip causing the difference in spacing. I had originally used the [parbox=false] option so that paragraphs would have the empty lines between them, but I found out I can do that manually with `\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}` before the paragraphs and `\setlength{\parskip}{0pc}` after the paragraphs, eliminating the need to use [parbox=false]. Not setting the parbox option to false fixes the issue.